# Recent Chrome update breaking td rowspan?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which I expect to render like:

```
+---------+--------+
|         |        |
|         |        |
|         +--------+
|         |        |
|         |        |
+---------+--------+
```

And it does: On the *previous version* of Chrome, IE10, Firefox, and every other browser/version combination I've tried.

The newest version of Chrome (26.0.1410.43 m) renders the table like this:

```
+---------+--------+
|         |        |
|         |        |
|         |        |
|         |        |
|         |        |
+---------+--------+
          |        |
          |        |
          |        |
          +--------+
```

Is my markup flawed and only the new Chrome detects this? Or is this a bug in Chrome or Webkit? I've searched for bugs on the [Chromium bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) but haven't found anything that addresses this issue.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.net of this? May be a stylesheet or other issue. (follow-up: appears to work [in isolation](http://jsfiddle.net/xptLE/))

Comment: After making a fiddle, and seeing it work, I found that it was my reset stylesheet adding `vertical-align: baseline;` to, well, everything. I still don't understand why it works in **every** browser except the new chrome.

Comment: So, I would say that if anything changed it was chrome handling that CSS style differently. ;-) Post what you'd added as an answer and accept it; this could be a problem someone else comes across down the road and would like to know the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After making a fiddle I found that it does work by itself. Adding `vertical-align: baseline;` to the table elements in my reset CSS caused the behavior above. I'm still wondering if its a bug since it works in every other browser including older versions of Chrome.

**Short answer**: Check your stylesheet(s) for `vertical-align: baseline;` being applied to table elements.

Comment: You can accept your own question now (i would guess)